# How to negate a predicate supplied by `std::bind`?

Tags: c++

For generic algorithms, we may use `std::bind` to supply a predicate. 
How can we negate that predicate?

As an example, consider a program that finds the first element in a `vector` that is *divisible* by 3.

```
bool is_divisible(int m, int n)
{
    return m % n == 0;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 3, 6, 9, 11, 15 };
    int n = 3;
    auto it = find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), bind(is_divisible, _1, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to find the first element that is *indivisible* by 3, by negating the predicate supplied by `bind`. How can I do it?

I have tried

```
auto it = find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), not1(bind(is_divisible, _1, n)));
```

which produces follwing error

```
error: no type named 'argument_type' in 
'struct std::_Bind<bool(*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int, int)>' class unary_negate
```

*Please do not suggest using lambdas or `find_if_not`, which is not the purpose of this question.*

Thanks very much!

Comment: not suggesting, but still curious why you want to use `bind` instead of a lambda, I find `bind` terrible to work with and one of the places where lambdas are super useful

Comment: can you please add the compiler error, for the "does not compile" line?

Comment: Also note that [`std::not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) have been deprecated in C++17 in favor of the new [`std::not_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn).

Comment: @user463035818 Thanks! I asked this question just out of curiosity of the language. For you information, the first compiler (g++ 7.1) error is `error: no type named 'argument_type' in 'struct std::_Bind<bool (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int, int)>' class unary_negate`

Comment: I added the error to your question, please note that error messages should be included in the question (not just in comments)

Comment: @user463035818 noted with thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you like `bind`, just `bind` some more:

```
find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::bind(std::logical_not<bool>(),
                                        std::bind(is_divisible, _1, n)));
```

(Of course, if you have access to C++17 `not_fn`, you can just use that.)

Answer (score 3):

You might use the replacement one: `std::not_fn` (C++17):

```
auto it = find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), not_fn(bind(is_divisible, _1, n)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)-able compiler and standard library, it can be done with [`std::not_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn):

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), not_fn(bind(is_divisible, _1, n)));
```

Which forwards to, and negates the result of any predicate functor.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
auto it = find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), not1<function<bool (int)>>(bind(is_divisible, std::placeholders::_1, n)));
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works. I didn't realize I should explicitly supply the type `function<bool (int)>` to `not1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a third parameter with which you say whether you are looking for a divisible element or not:

```
bool is_divisible(int m, int n, bool is_divisible)
{
    return is_divisible == (m % n == 0);
}
```