# C++: How to define a generic not predicate from another predicate

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a predicate:

```
bool my_pred(const MyType* x) {
    ....
}
```

and I want to filter some collection so it only contains the elements that do not match `my_pred`. Ideally, I would like to write something like this:

```
using namespace std;
vector<const MyType*> elems = ...;
remove_if(begin(elems), end(elems), not(my_pred));
```

How do I write the `not` higher-order function above?

The aim is to achieve the following (but this code does not work, of course):

```
template<typename T>
function<bool(T)> not(function<bool(T)> pred) {
    return [&](T x) { return !pred(x) };
}
```

I tried using `std::logical_not`, but I failed. I want to avoid having to define a specific lambda every time I want to do something like this.

Ideally, I would like to extend this pattern to other logical operators.
Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly have you tried `std::logical_not`?

Comment: `std::not_fn` maybe? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn

Comment: C++17 has not_fn http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn

Comment: @yeputons - that's not gonna work. You want `std::not1` (or `std::not_fn` since C++17)

Comment: if you don't want to use any of the std predicates you can either use a binder or you can use a functor (make sure it's a stateless functor, otherwise remove_if will have unexpected results cause the predicate is passed by a copy)

Comment: Dupe worthy maybe? [How to negate a predicate supplied by `std::bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922850/how-to-negate-a-predicate-supplied-by-stdbind/48923002#48923002)

Comment: lambda ? `[](auto&& e){ return !my_pred(e); }` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Bearing in mind that using 'auto' in lambda parameters will  require at least C++14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
template<typename T>
function<bool(T)> not(function<bool(T)> pred) {
    return [&](T x) { return !pred(x) };
}
```

you capture by reference, but lambda life longer than its capture `pred`, that leads to dangling pointer and UB.

You should capture by copy or move:

```
template<typename T>
function<bool(T)> not(function<bool(T)> pred) {
    return [=](T x) { return !pred(x) };
}
```

You may get rid of overhead of `std::function` by being more generic:

```
template<typename F>
auto not(F pred) {
    return [=](auto&& x) { return !pred(x); };
}
```

(require C++14).